# Command line on Windows to get latest files from FTP site

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

I need a batch scripts run from command line on Windows, which downloads latest files from FTP site (the latest files might have more than a files sometimes).

I have used the following command from `WinSCP.com` but I only get one latest file. Can give me some direction?

```
get -latest *.txt
```

Wxample: with above command I only get filename `XYZ.txt` file only, I wish have a scripts manage to get both `ABC.txt` and `ZZZ.txt`.

```
filename        last written date
------------    ----------------------
ABC.txt         2016-01-01
ZZZ.txt         2016-01-01
A123.txt        2015-12-10
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `get -latest *.txt`

Comment: How do you expect the script to recognize what are "your latest" files?

Comment: maybe i would say to download all files in a directory with maximum last written date. with above example the maximum last written date is 2016-01-01, hence the scripts will return ABC.txt & ZZZ.txt.

Comment: So edit your question to make your requirement clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in command to download multiple files based on date, we'll have to do it manually.

The standard `ls` output is human-readable but not sortable by date:

> ```
> D---------   0                           0 Aug 21 15:32:37 2016 Default
> ```

We'll need an xml log using `/xmllog=` parameter:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<session xmlns="........." name="USER@localhost" start="2016-08-23T15:41:10.708Z">
  <ls>
    <destination value="/temp" />
    <files>
      <file>
        <filename value=".." />
        <type value="D" />
        <modification value="1899-12-30T02:00:00.000Z" />
        <permissions value="---------" />
      </file>
```

Good, each file has a machine-readable date, name, type (D for directory, we'll skip them).

---

**The batch file.**
<sup>(comment separators are also part of code)</sup>

```
@echo off
```

> : Setup

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "WinSCP=C:\somepath\WinSCP.com"
set "ftp=ftp://USER:PASSWORD@ftp.server.com"
set "remoteFolder=/someFolderNoTrailingSlash"
```

> : List all ftp files

```
"%WinSCP%" ^
    /command "open %ftp%" "ls ""%remoteFolder%""" "exit" ^
    /xmllog="%temp%\ftplog.xml" >nul
(
    set isDirectory=
    for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=<= " %%a in ('type "%temp%\ftplog.xml"') do (
        if "%%a"=="filename"     (set "line=%%~b" & set isDirectory=)
        if "%%a"=="type" if "%%~b"=="D" (set isDirectory=yes)
        if "%%a"=="modification" if not defined isDirectory (
            set "line=%%~b*!line!"
            echo !line!
        )
    )
) > "%temp%\ftplist.txt"
```

> : Sort by date and make a WinSCP script to get the latest files with same date

```
set lastDate=
(
    echo open %ftp%
    for /f "delims=* tokens=1,2" %%a in ('
        sort /reverse "%temp%\ftplist.txt"
    ') do (
        for /f "delims=T" %%c in ("%%a") do set thisDate=%%c
        if defined lastDate (
            if not !thisDate!==!lastDate! goto download
        ) else (
            set lastDate=!thisDate!
        )
        echo get -preservetime "%remoteFolder%/%%b"
    )
) > "%temp%\ftpscript.txt"
if not defined lastDate goto cleanup
```

> : Download and cleanup temporary files

```
:download
"%WinSCP%" /script="%temp%\ftpscript.txt" /command "exit"

:cleanup
del "%temp%\ftplog.xml" "%temp%\ftplist.txt" "%temp%\ftpscript.txt"

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is doable with plain WinSCP scripting and a batch file, as the [answer by @wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39076806/850848#39106409) shows, the code would be much more readable in a more advanced language like PowerShell with a use of the [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).

The code below is partially based on example [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).

```
param (
    $session = "ftp://USER:PASSWORD@ftp.server.com",
    $remotePath = "/remote/path",
    $localPath = "C:\local\path"
)

try
{
    Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
    $sessionOptions.ParseUrl($session)

    try
    {
        Write-Host "Connecting..."
        $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        $files = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath).Files
 
        $latest_file =
            $files |
            Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } |
            Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
            Select-Object -First 1

        Write-Host (
            "Latest file is $latest_file created on $($latest_file.LastWriteTime)")
        
        $day = Get-Date -date $latest_file.LastWriteTime -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0

        $latest_files =
            $files |
            Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } |
            Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $day }

        Write-Host "Downloading $($latest_files.Count) files created after $day"

        foreach ($file in $latest_files)
        {
            $path = $file.FullName
            Write-Host $path
            $session.GetFiles(
                [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask($path),
                (Join-Path $localPath $file.Name)).Check()
        }

        Write-Host "Done"
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    exit 1
}
```